# Handling Soft Deletes in Informatica Source Qualifier

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I need to compare the target table data with its multiple Input tables for the different source systems of them for doing soft deletes.
Please note that input tables of the target will vary for each system code as few system codes data is available in more than 1 table
and few is available in  one table only. In addition to that input table does not have historical data where as these tables are truncate and
reload on daily basis but the target table has historical data as its not truncate and reload process.

Here I need to write the code in below scenarios.

1. when all the input tables have the data for same source code system then in that case , the target table compares data with all the three input tables and do soft deletes when target table data is not available in one of the input table at least.
2. when any of the the input tables have the data for same source code system then in that case , the target table compares data with
   those 2 input tables and do soft deletes when target table data is not available in one of the input table at least.
3. when the individual table has the data for the source code system then in that case, the target table compares data with
   that particular input table and do soft deletes when target table data is not available in that input table.

I need to handle this in Informatica source qualifier.

Example::

```
Target table : TARGET

ID SOURCE_SYSTEM DELETE_FLG
12345   AB         N            
98745   AB         N
08765   AB         N
69523   BA         N
34123   BA         N
78912   DF          N
11234   JK           N
2345      DK         Y(HERE Y MEANS SOFT DELETED)

INPUT TABLE1: INPUT_TABLE1

ID  SOURCE_SYSTEM      DELETE_FLG
12345   AB         N
34123   BA         N


INPUT TABLE2: INPUT_TABLE2

ID  SOURCE_SYSTEM      DELETE_FLG
12345   AB         N
23451   DK         N

INPUT TABLE3: INPUT_TABLE3

ID  SOURCE_SYSTEM      DELETE_FLG
78912   DF          N
11234   JK           N
```

DESIRED OUTPUT: TARGET

```
ID SOURCE_SYSTEM DELETE_FLG
12345   AB         N
98745   AB         Y (SHOULD BE SOFT DELETED)
08765   AB         Y (SHOULD BE SOFT DELETED)
69523   BA         Y (SHOULD BE SOFT DELETED)
34123   BA         N
78912   DF          N
11234   JK           N
23451   DK         N
2345      DK         Y(HERE Y MEANS SOFT DELETED. Its already soft deleted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple post load mapping to update the flag.

step1 - read from Target in SQ.

step2 - create a looukup on table1. Lookup on `ID`. Lets assume return column is lkp_table1_id

step3 - create a expression to create the delete flag like below

```
iif( isnull(lkp_table1_id) and isnull(lkp_table2_id) and isnull(lkp_table3_id),'Y,'N' )
```

step 4 - connect this to update strategy and then to the target. in Update strategy set it to `DD_UPDATE` and in the target set `ID` column as Primary Key.

Your mapping will look like this -

```
       |--> LKP1 
SQ --> |--> LKP2   --> EXP --> TGT
       |--> LKP3
```